# Azure stream analytics : How to ingest image to Azure hub in real time from my client system?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics, data-ingestion

I want to send images from my system continuously to Azure cloud and process the image on the cloud using Azure stream analytics.

Following are my requirements:

1. Send images from a client(my desktop) continuously to Azure.
2. Run my ML algorithm on the cloud on the received images.
3. Send the result(output image and metadata) back to the client(my system)

Which services/product of Azure would help me in doing this task in real-time??? And what the steps??

Answer (score 0):

Azure Stream Analytics would most likely not be a good fit for this (not saying that you couldn't use it) since I would assume your image data would be rather large. You should rather look into [Azure Machine Learning scoring web services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-consume-web-service) for that. That way you can expose a web service that you can send your image to (e.g. with a POST request), score it, and get the result back.

However: there are many possible ways here and it really depends on your actual problem you are trying to solve. (I almost voted to close this question)

Comment: Thanks for the information. My requirement is to send images of resolution 640 x 480 , 3 channel image(RGB image) to azure cloud continuously from the client system, run the custom ML/DL algorithm in server on the images received from the cloud and send back the result( image and/or metadata) back to the client in real -time.

Comment: The image resolution does not matter as much as the actual image size (as in bytes). Depending on the size, you could send them into an Azure Event Hub and have an Azure Function being triggered from there to call the ML scoring endpoint. Or, if the images get bigger, you might want to consider to directly upload them to blob storage and have a blob-triggered Function.

Comment: Which cloud service is better to ingest images to cloud and run custom model on the image in cloud?? Azure (event hub) / AWS Kinesis video stream / Google cloud / Kafka /PyZmq ???